# Bloomberg API and BLOT command

Tags: bloomberg

I'm looking through the Bloomberg API and trying to find if it supports pulling down the output of the BLOT command that displays your trade history.

It seems to mostly support market data (historical/reference and otherwise) and your personal portfolio data, as well as the ESQ screens.  I have implemented our business's data fetches for those.  But what I would love to find is where it had output of general commands such as BLOT.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: hi kevin, I was wondering whether after all this time you found a solution